# Retaliation after grade dispute (story shortened)

Tags: advisor, united-states, grades, salary, abuse

After submitting my grade dispute request to my department (STEM field), my advisor started to become abusive towards me. Originally I speculated that the department may have let him know the fact that I disputed my grades. Not until recently, I became aware that he was actually called upon by the Graduate Program Director to serve on the 3-person committee to review the dispute.

1. My advisor placed me on "probation" in the middle of the semester (four days after I submitted the grade dispute), citing underperformance. I cannot find the mechanism for such "probation" anywhere. There was no prior warning.
2. My advisor also decided to cut my stipend to a level that is far from sufficient to pay my bills (one-third of the original level). My job duties are not reduced. I am a full-time PhD student. My stipend is now below $1k.
3. He has become unreasonable. And his evaluation is crucial to my success. Also, if his change of attitude towards me stemmed from the grade dispute, and he doesn't want to be transparent about it, that basically means I cannot rely on his evaluation to make changes to please him. The action of grade dispute cannot be undone. The advisor type I want to work with is: 1) unhappy and vote against me in the dispute and 2) warn me to not do this anymore, instead of taking a series of cruel actions to punish me.

What should I do?

P.S.: there is definitely a lot of information that is not included. But the main part of the story has been described.

Comment: Seems a lot of bother for one class where you might get a B+ vs an A-...

Comment: IME, this is, painfully, classic "A-" student behavior. A lot of incorrect perceptions and assumptions, an enormous of wasted verbiage and effort to no good end, and a lot of churn over a negligible difference in grade.

Comment: ... in short: everything here signals, "inability to identify and focus on big issues".

Comment: Do you *want* a PhD, and to do research, or is research a chore? It's strange to me to see a PhD as a stepping stone to a law degree. Why do you think your future plans should affect how you are graded on work you do today?

Answer (score 4):

I won't answer all of your points/questions, but will only attempt the ones that seem to me the most important.

First, most universities will have an ombudsman exactly for this type of issues. These don't have any actual powers to solve problems, but they are deputized to bring people into meetings, tell you about your real options in the context of your institution, etc. Depending on the size of your university, there might be a dean whose job is solving these disputes. In my experience, these people know how vulnerable PhD students are, and do what can be done.

Second, your points about the pettiness of some professors are true. Why would a professor care about a grade dispute? Either the student deserves the credit or not. And it's not like if the A- comes out the professor's salary. And the petty ones are the most likely to go into retaliation mode, which might be what is happening to you.

Having said that, keep in mind that from the professor's side, 95% of the time when a student comes with a story like yours, there's a lot of missing information, misstatements from the student, etc. Too many times I call people (Registrar's, the other professor involved, etc.) to hear back "did the student also tell you he didn't show up for the first half of the semester, didn't he?" And then I ask the student and he/she admits to it, and adds "but it's still unfair, I didn't mean to be absent" or some other lame excuse. So it's not that professors band together. I (and my colleagues) are always looking to do right for other 5%, but please understand that we are applying some Bayesian stats. I'm not saying you are in the 95%, just explaining the skepticism you might see when telling your case.

Now, if you are right, and your advisor is actually retaliating over something this petty, your best (only?) option is to get out of there. However the dispute ends, change advisors, change programs, or change universities. There are many, many examples of people who have done it.

Comment: I wish the ombuds where I was did not have any actual power. Faculty were always guilty unless they could prove otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like probation *is the warning*.

Unilateral changes to stipends would be absolutely forbidden in the systems I'm familiar with, it's simply not a thing an advisor can do. You will have to check whether that's the case with yours, but if it is permitted I don't see what you can do about it besides opt to leave.

We don't know why your professor is doing these things. You assume it's the grade dispute, but that seems unlikely to me unless it's part of a broader pattern of your behavior. I think you should have a conversation with your advisor. It may be that there is something that can be fixed, but overall to me this sounds like an unsalvageable relationship where your advisor has lost any confidence in you and wants you to leave. Given their importance for your graduate studies, you likely cannot continue without their support.

Your options at that point would be to find another advisor within your program or quit.

Comment: After I learned that he directly participated in the grade dispute review, I look back at all the conversations I had with him after the notice of probation. Everything that happened during that week starts to make sense. Every word he said starts to make sense.

Comment: To the point that @Bryan Krause is making about the stipend, I agree in that I've never seen an unilateral stipend reduction. People have RAs or TAs (different names at different places), and if you don't have RAs, you teach until you have enough money. Are they forbidding you from teaching?

Comment: What does “unilateral stipend reduction” mean? Does stipend reduction also need my agreement? The process in my department is just my advisor sent an email to me as a notice of stipend reduction. Then I am out of the process. It’s all handled by department and payroll. They just put the number the advisor gave to them, and approved it at every level. I am asked to do research. My job duties remain the same. I think their intent is to use stipend reduction to punish my prior underperformance (which I obviously have an different opinion ). And if they say my work isn’t satisfactory, 1/2

Comment: 2/2 I will continue to be paid at this insanely reduced rate. I also don’t believe this can happen to any student before. I am a little bit disappointed about how the payroll works here. Nobody blocks this. The chair is not American born but he has lived here for a long time. I just have a strong feeling that it isn’t right. The stipend for a full-time PhD student cannot be reduced below $1000 a month. This doesn’t sound American. Payroll I understand why they approve quickly, because they don’t know the context. They may think it’s just a student worker chooses to do less work.

Comment: I think it’s not uncommon for PhD advisors to use poor performance to kick students out of their group. I also need to think very carefully about this. This is really toxic. I don’t even know how to fight.

Comment: @Ioannis Where I am from in the US, stipends are generally fixed and cannot be changed. I don't know where you are from, but if it's in the US it seems very strange to me. And yes, if a student is performing poorly they can get kicked out of PhD programs. A PhD is something earned, not automatically given for being in a program, and I don't know why you would think otherwise.

Comment: @BryanKrause it’s in the US. You still assume the “poor performance” is true. The whole topic is about retaliation. And I would sincerely ask for your advice - how I can improve my performance if I am doing well in everything my advisor had used to prove I perform poorly (and those things were made known to me only at the time of probation, not before), then what else I can do? It seems he is still not satisfied.

Comment: @Ioannis I would check with someone in the ombuds office or the leadership of your graduate program. Stipend level is not usually under PIs control. Like I wrote at the end of my answer, if your relationship with your PI is broken you likely need a different advisor.

Comment: @BryanKrause thanks for sharing your advice. one dilemma is the leadership of the program they will almost always support the faculty's decision, very similar to the grade dispute situation. I just don't know if it is legal to punish a student by reducing his stipend. Can the stipend be dependent on the quality of work (although I won't agree that my quality is lower than others)? For the same work, there will always be people who did better and people who did just ok. So the stipend is adjusted dynamically at any time just based on the advisor's opinion (and his "evidence")?

Comment: @Ioannis It's up to your institution. In my experience it's a fixed rate per the terms of your graduate assistantship.